# Is the Thread really stop when I use new Thread().interrupt();?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I create a `Thread` like the following code. This `Thread` will send the `POST request`.(The code is not yet written , so I didn't post the detail code of `Thread` )

```
final Runnable Update_Value = new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            **// It will send the POST request to the Server**

        }
    };
```

I use the `new Thread(Update_Value).start();` to run the Thread.

And I use `new Thread(Update_Value).interrupt();` to interrupt the Thread.

**1. If I use `new Thread(Update_Value).start();` to run the `Thread`.**

**2 How to interrupt the Thread when I using `new Thread(Update_Value).start();` ?**

**3 Is the thread close when App close if I didn't close it ?**

Sorry about my English...Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

1. If you use `new` Thread each time, the two calls create two different threads; they don't act on the same thread.
2. The `interrupt()` method does not stop the thread.  Rather, it tells the thread to take a look at any interrupt flags that may also have been set, such as a shutdown flag.  The thread itself must contain code to check for interrupts and to check for flags such as shutdown flags.

Comment: how about if you assign the thread with null? does it stop the thread?

Comment: @KickButtowski No, you have to handle the interrupt yourself in the Thread. It's pretty simple. Use the `isInterrupted()` method for getting out of loops and catch `InterruptedException`.

Comment: @KickButtowski You don't assign null to a Thread. You assign null to a variable referencing a Thread. After assigning null, the variable no longer references that Thread. If the Thread were a regular Object, and there were no other references, it would eventually be garbage-collected. A Thread, however, will happily continue running, without anyone referencing it.

Comment: @KickButtowski It is not good practice in the sense that it just doesn't have any effect.

Answer (score 1):

`interrupt` method is used to send an interrupt signal to a running thread. Calling on a new thread does not make sense.

To properly handle the interrupt signal, your thread code should catch InterruptedException. Something like this:

```
try {

      // do thread task

} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // interrupted: if required do something on interrupt or simply return
    return;
}
```